# how to show all (or many) Attributes in Description.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.8

I wish to show attributes `(file: attributes.phtml)` content in Description.phtml ,somebody answer but i find it is not the key.
 here is the two files:

```
    <?php
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
        $_product = $this->getProduct()
    ?>
    <?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>

<h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>


    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
   <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
     <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif;?>


    <?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>



<?php if ($_description): ?>




<div id="adtop"></div>
<div id="adbottom"></div>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
<div id="detailHtml"> <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?> </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i dont know why my codes canot be shown current here.i means put one tabs content to another (the 2nd attributes to 1st product content)

Comment: file1 is :\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\attributes.phtml  file2 is \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\description.phtml

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show user selected product items. You can use configurable product. The configurable product shows you selected product.
The configurable product created steps are-

1. Go to `Catalog->attributes->manage attributes->add new attribute` and add your attribute with `'Catalog Input Type for Store Owner'=dropdown` select.
2. Make sure the value of `'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end'` are set `'Yes'`.
3. Go to `Catalog->attributes->manage attribute sets` and add your attribute to attribute group.
4. Go to `Catalog->Manage Products->Add Product` and `set Product Type = Configurable Product`.
5. Select your attribute and click `continue` button.
6. Set all product information and go to `Associated Product` and set your attribute value.
7. Click to `Save` button.

Comment: not this question! i meant show ATTRIBUTES content(TAB) in DESCRIPTION (TAB)...